# Code Igniter Calendar | Inserting {day} outside of the template

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

This is basically the entire code. I'm trying to display in the calendar day if there are available time slots to book an appointment. There are 3 available per day. It checks the number of used time slots and uses the switch statement to echo how many are left.

```
$count = $this->cal->countByDate($this->uri->segment(2) . "-" . $this->uri->segment(3) . "-" . "22");
    $testswitch = 0;
    switch ($count) {
        case '0':
            $testswitch = 'Three Available Time Slots <br><br><a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Book Appointment</a>';
            break;
        case '1':
            $testswitch = 'Two Available Time Slots <br><br><a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Book Appointment</a>';
            break;
        case '2':
            $testswitch = 'One Available Time Slot <br><br><a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Book Appointment</a>';
            break;
        case '3':
            $testswitch = 'No Available Time Slots';
            break;

        default:
            $testswitch = 'Something Is Broken';
            break;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($count);
    echo "</pre>";
    $yolo = true;
    //PREFS
    $prefs = array(
    'start_day'    => 'monday',
    'month_type'   => 'long',
    'day_type'     => 'long',
    'show_next_prev'  => TRUE,
    'next_prev_url'   => base_url('schedule/'),
    );


$prefs['template'] = '
{table_open}<table class="calendar">{/table_open}
{week_day_cell}<th class="day_header">{week_day}</th>{/week_day_cell}
{cal_cell_content}<span class="day_listing"><a href="{content}">{day}</a></span>&nbsp; ' . 
"{$testswitch}"
 . '&nbsp;{/cal_cell_content}
{cal_cell_content_today}<div class="today"><span class="day_listing"><a href="{content}">{day}</a></span>&nbsp; {content}</div>{/cal_cell_content_today}
{cal_cell_no_content}<span class="day_listing">{day}</span>&nbsp;{/cal_cell_no_content}
{cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="today"><span class="day_listing">{day}</span></div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}
```

';

My issue is:

```
$count = $this->cal->countByDate($this->uri->segment(2) . "-" . $this->uri->segment(3) . "-" . "22");
```

I need to turn that day, "22", into {day} so the calendar will input the day for me.

Like it uses it in the template here:

```
{cal_cell_no_content}<span class="day_listing">{day}</span>&nbsp;{/cal_cell_no_content}
```